# How to develop a webpart that show report of a list

Tags: 2007, development, web-part

I'm final year student and I need to develop a webpart for SharePoint 2007. I'm still exploring and I search for a tutor and friends that can point me to right direction on how to do my project.

I have a list that contain 5 columns :

They are Title, Broadcast Date, Business Unit, Type of Project and Channel.

So, I want to develop a webpart that has a drop-down menu that user can choose to filter their list and show report.

This webpart need to be develop on different pages from that list.I'm asking here, can it be develop in SharePoint 2007?

Anyone can help me develop this?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't use standard List View Web Part?

Comment: Because it most likely a home work :)

Comment: Probably an instance of them trying to learn C# or XSLT and the instructor not knowing the basic fundamentals of the platform they're developing on (like a lot of development focused people).

Comment: I need to develop something like this :  http://www.kwizcom.com/sharepoint-add-ons/sharepoint-list-filter-plus/overview/

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually you can filter any sharepoint list OOTB, just click on the list column-header to filter on a single value (just like in excel).

To get started on WebPart development you might want to look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms452873%28v=office.12%29.aspx.

Comment: I want to develop something like this : http://www.kwizcom.com/sharepoint-add-ons/sharepoint-list-filter-plus/overview/

Answer (score 0):

You will need:

- Visual Studio 2008
- SharePoint 2007 server access

I would also recommend getting [WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/) because it will help you with some of the harder deployment stuff. Here is [pretty good post outlining a lot](http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2009/04/08/wspbuilder-walkthrough-of-the-visual-studio-add-in.aspx) of what WSPBuilder can help you with and you can just focus on the WebPart section.